# Remove a substring using Regex

Tags: .net, html, regex, html-parsing

It would be great if someone could help me with the regex. This is my code:

```
Regex.Replace("<_img src=\"abc.png\" /><_img class=\"shwimg\" alt=\"\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" src=\"/images/img/do.png\" />",
                    "<_img .*? src=\"/images/img/do.png\" />", string.Empty)
```

I need to remove the occurrence of the string:

```
<_img class="shwimg" alt="" width="20" height="20" src="/images/img/do.png" />
```

The order of the occurence of

```
class="shwimg" alt="" width="20" height="20"
```

may vary, hence I've given `.*?` in the pattern. However, the pattern I've given doesnt work and I'm not able to replace the string.

Comment: Hmm. _html. very clever.

Comment: Use a !@#$%&*ing HTML parser.

Comment: Ok, now really - is this your code, or are you having trouble with the Stack Overflow formatting?

Comment: To rephrase @Matt's comment, you may not be using the best available tool for the job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Is this the regex you're looking for?:

```
<_img [^>]*src="/images/img/do.png" />
```

(here's the same with escaped double-quotes, ready for use in your Regex.Replace call):

```
"<_img [^>]*src=\"/images/img/do.png\" />"
```